# Ajax response is not returning in sorted form laravel controller

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I am fetching data from database then adding one more property to that object which is distance. and sorting object data based on that property. When I dd() it in controller to check if data is sorted or not. I see that data is sorted but when I return it as JSON response it returned as it comed from database.

controller function

```
 public function search(Request $request)
    {
 

    $providers = Provider::get()->map(function($item) use($request){
        $item->setAttribute('distance',$this->addDistanceToProvider($item,$request)) ;
        return $item;
    })->sortBy('distance');

    dd($providers);
        return response()->json($providers);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the result of `sortBy()` keeps the original array keys, hence when sent as a json response it is received in javascript as an object (of objects) and in javascript objects are unsorted.

So we need to chain `values()` after `sortBy()` to reset the keys which will result in javascript receiving an array (of objects) so the sorting done in controller is retained

```php
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $providers = Provider::get()->map(function($item) use($request){
        $item->setAttribute('distance',$this->addDistanceToProvider($item,$request)) ;
        return $item;
    })->sortBy('distance')->values();

    
    return response()->json($providers);

}
```

Try this and the sort order will be retained in the frontend as well